# yum update to the specific version of package

Tags: linux, yum, openssl

I am using yum update command to update openssl on Linux machine.

The command is

```
# yum update openssl
```

To update to to a specific version

```
Say If I want to update this to the specific version like 1.0.0e.
```

I currently have Openssl 0.9.8w in my machine.

Is this possible to do this.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only update to whatever version of the openssl package is available in the yum repositories. You can check to see which openssl package is available by entering the command:

```
yum list available openssl
```

On RHEL5, the version available at this time is openssl-0.9.8e-22.el5_8.4.

On RHEL6, the current version is openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.

If you are on an RHEL5 or CentOS5 machine, you cannot update to the openssl-1.0.0 package that is only available for RHEL6 or CentOS6.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But Can I download the source code manually and I can install it right. http://j3pd.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/upgrading-openssl/.    Please suggest.

Comment: Installing OpenSSL the way that web site suggests does not involve `yum` and will result in there being two versions of OpenSSL on your system. Depending upon what you are trying to do, this should be okay as long as you install this additional OpenSSL version into the suggested location, /usr/local/openssl.